# How do I create tabbed UI in codeIgniter with jquery UI?

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-ui-tabs

am using codeIgniter to develop a web app and for my UI, I want to use jQuery-UI-Tabs. 
I am locked down as to how to get my views to show up in their respective tabs. Any help?

Comment: Yeah, am very sorry. I tend to load my views using the controller/method style but content is not able to load.  Tabs always show loading and nothing else afterwards. Help me out here. My code is shown below:

Comment: follow up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419386/jquery-tabs-with-codeigniterpagination-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you want to do it.

If you want to pre-load all the views separately, and have it there, then here's how:

In CodeIgniter:

```
$views['pageOne'] = $this->load->view('view_name', $data, true);
$views['pageTwo'] = $this->load->view('view_name2', $data, true);
```

in jQuery UI Tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <?php echo $pageOne;?>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <?php echo $pageTwo;?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Another way would be the [Ajax](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) way.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="link-to-controller">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="link-to-controller">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```